# Jquery Image Bubble diplay: inline-block Issue

Tags: css

Previously, I was trying to determine how to remove the padding which causes the space between the images before bubbling.

The display: inline-block was causing the padding.  It was reccomended to have all of the li tags run together to resolve that, however, that isnt possible because I need to have the li tags as they would appear normally within an html document, not side-by-side.

I have commented the: display: inline-block, and this now causes the images to appear stacked on top of each other, when they need to be side-by-side for the width of the yellow container.

http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/nvQEA/5/

Could someone advise me on what I should modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the white space between the yellow boxes, you need to run the li tags together. The inline-block declaration is causing the extra spacing.

```
        <li>stuff here</li><li>here is more
           stuff</li>
```

Comment: why would that make a difference?

Comment: By design browsers maintain white space between inline elements.

Comment: I commented the display:inline-block;

Comment: I also increased the width of the yellow container.  I need to be able to have the code formatted without having the li tags run together.  Since I commented the display: inline-block, the images now appear on top of each other, when they need to appear side-by-side, can you advise me on what I can change?: http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/nvQEA/5/

Comment: You could try using float: left instead of setting a display value.